# Reduce sequence by parts

Tags: scala, collections

I have a sequence `Seq[T]` and I want to do partial reduce. For example for a `Seq[Int]` I want to get `Seq[Int]` consisting of the longest partial sums of monotonic regions. For example:

```
val s = Seq(1, 2, 4, 3, 2, -1, 0, 6, 8)
groupMonotionic(s) = Seq(1 + 2 + 4, 3 + 2 + (-1), 0 + 6 + 8)
```

I was looking for some method like conditional fold with the signature `fold(z: B)((B, T) => B, (T, T) => Boolean)` where the predicate states for where to terminate current sum aggregation, but it seems there is no something like that in the subtrait hierarchy of `Seq`.

What would be a solution using Scala Collection API and without using mutable variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way amongst many to do this (using `Scala 2.13`'s [`List#unfold`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html#unfold[A,S](init:S)(f:S=%3EOption[(A,S)]):CC[A])):

```
// val items = Seq(1, 2, 4, 3, 2, -1, 0, 6, 8)
items match {
  case first :: _ :: _ =>                // If there are more than 2 items
    List
      .unfold(items.sliding(2).toList) { // We slid items to work on pairs of consecutive items
        case Nil =>                      // No more items to unfold
          None                           // None signifies the end of the unfold
        case rest @ Seq(a, b) :: _ =>    // We span based on the sign of a-b
          Some(rest.span(x => (x.head - x.last).signum == (a-b).signum))
      }
      .map(_.map(_.last))                // back from slided pairs
      match { case head :: rest => (first :: head) :: rest }
  case _ =>                              // If there is 0 or 1 item
    items.map(List(_))
}
// List(List(1, 2, 4), List(3, 2, -1), List(0, 6, 8))
```

`List.unfold` iterates as long as the unfolding function provides `Some`. It starts with an initial state which is the list of items to unfold. At each iteration, we `span` the state (remaining elements to unfold) based on the sign of the heading two elements difference. The unfolded elements are heading items sharing the same monotony and the unfolding state becomes the other remaining elements.

`List#span` splits a list into a tuple whose first part contains elements matching the predicate applied until the predicate stops being valid. The second part of the tuple contains the rest of the elements. Which fits perfectly the expected return type of `List.unfold`'s unfolding function, which is `Option[(A, S)]` (In this case `Option[(List[Int], List[Int])]`).

`Int.signum` returns `-1`, `0` or `1` depending on the sign of the integer it's applied on.

Note that the first item has to be put back in the result as it hasn't an ancestor determining its signum (`match { case head :: rest => (first :: head) :: rest }`).

To apply the reducing function (in this case a sum), we can map the final result: `.map(_.sum)`

Answer (score 3):

Works in Scala 2.13+ with `cats`

```
import scala.util.chaining._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._

val s = List(1, 2, 4, 3, 2, -1, 0, 6, 8)

def isLocalExtrema(a: List[Int]) =
    a.max == a(1) || a.min == a(1)

implicit class ListOps[T](ls: List[T]) {
  def multiSpanUntil(f: T => Boolean): List[List[T]] = ls.span(f) match {
    case (h, Nil) => List(h)
    case (h, t) => (h ::: t.take(1)) :: t.tail.multiSpanUntil(f)
  }
}

def groupMonotionic(groups: List[Int]) = groups match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x  if x.length < 3 => List(groups.sum)      
  case _ =>

    groups
      .sliding(3).toList
      .map(isLocalExtrema)
      .pipe(false :: _ ::: List(false))
      .zip(groups)
      .multiSpanUntil(!_._1)
      .pipe(Nested.apply)
      .map(_._2)
      .value
      .map(_.sum)

}

println(groupMonotionic(s))
//List(7, 4, 14)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `foldLeft` to traverse the numeric list with a Tuple3 accumulator `(listOfLists, prevElem, prevTrend)` that stores the `previous element` and `previous trend` to conditionally assemble a `list of lists` in the current iteration:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 4, 3, 2, -1, 0, 6, 8)

val isUpward = (a: Int, b: Int) => a < b

val initTrend = isUpward(list.head, list.tail.head)

val monotonicLists = list.foldLeft( (List[List[Int]](), list.head, initTrend) ){
  case ((lol, prev, prevTrend), curr) =>
    val currTrend = isUpward(curr, prev)
    if (currTrend == prevTrend)
      ((curr :: lol.head) :: lol.tail , curr, currTrend)
    else
      (List(curr) :: lol , curr, currTrend)
}._1.reverse.map(_.reverse)
// monotonicLists: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 4), List(3, 2, -1), List(0, 6, 8))
```

To sum the individual nested lists:

```
monotonicLists.map(_.sum)
// res1: List[Int] = List(7, 4, 14)
```